# Понизить в xcode версию прошивки ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем привет такая проблема, обновил xcode и разрабатываю, как выяснилось, под ios 14.2 а на телефоне 14.0.1. Вопрос такой как понизить версию приложения в xcode, что бы она стала ниже чем 14.0.1 и соответственно сбилделось (приложение) на телефон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в настройках проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все супер, спасибо большое. Как сайт разрешит поставлю галочку